# why EvtBadHeaderError appears when reading an .evt file in obspy

Tags: python, obspy

I am using a command called `read` on the *Obspy* library in Python. I am just trying to read a .evt file. However the following error appears:

`EvtBadHeaderError: Bad Frame values`

And my code is:

`from obspy import read
dt = read('evtfile.evt',format='KINEMETRICS_EVT')`

I searched for it and this error comes from this [EvtBadHeaderError](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/blob/master/obspy/io/kinemetrics/evt.py#LC332) webpage. I tried to contact someone on the obspy forum page but i didn't get any answer. So i am just trying to find out where this error comes from. So i am trying to "decode" this error but it is a little bit difficult for me to understand. I would appreciate if someone could explain me why this is happening. I dont't know if it is good that i ask this question here but it is about my master and i really need to find why this error appears. Thanks!!